# Unable to pass data validation when reference an object in Jira Assets (JSM) import schema

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-rest-api, jsm, atlassian-forge

I want to import external data in Jira Assets. I am following the instructions available and the schema - https://api.atlassian.com/jsm/assets/imports/external/schema/versions/2021_09_15

I using static data for the imports during the development process to simplify troubleshooting. Mainly I have:

- The schema file
- A data file devices
- A data file manufacturers

I want to reference a manufacturer to the device attributes using the type "referenced_object". Apparently I dont use the correct syntax because I get a data validation error.

```
INFO    22:19:17.451  812d3ec2a80b4dec811065ced224a263  {
  jsonValidationErrors: [],
  dataValidationErrors: [
    {
      code: 'MISSING_REFERENCE_OBJECT_TYPE_EXTERNAL_ID',
      location: 'Device.Manufacturer'
    }
  ],
  status: 'error'
}
```

I spent hours fiddling with the syntax, especially setting the "objectMappingIQL" string but was never able to make the import work.

My files look like this.

**schema**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://api.atlassian.com/jsm/assets/imports/external/schema/versions/2021_09_15",
    "schema": {
        "objectSchema": {
            "name": "dcim",
            "description": "Assets imported from NetBox DCIM",
            "objectTypes": [
                {
                    "externalId": "object-type/device",
                    "name": "Device",
                    "description": "A device is a physical asset that is managed by NetBox DCIM",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/device-id",
                            "name": "id",
                            "description": "The unique identifier of the device",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "label": false,
                            "unique": true
                        },
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/device-name",
                            "name": "Device Name",
                            "description": "The name of the device",
                            "type": "text",
                            "label": true
                        },
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/device-url",
                            "name": "Netbox URL",
                            "description": "Source URL of the device in Netbox",
                            "type": "url",
                            "label": false
                        },
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/device-manufacturer",
                            "name": "Manufacturer",
                            "description": "The manufacturer of the device",
                            "type": "referenced_object",
                            "referenceObjectExternalId": "object-type/manufacturer",
                            "referenceObjectTypeName": "Manufacturer",
                            "label": false,
                            "selector": "name"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "externalId": "object-type/manufacturer",
                    "name": "Manufacturer",
                    "description": "A manufacturer is a company that produces devices",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/manufacturer-id",
                            "name": "id",
                            "description": "The unique identifier of the manufacturer",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "label": false,
                            "unique": true
                        },
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/manufacturer-name",
                            "name": "Manufacturer Name",
                            "description": "The name of the manufacturer",
                            "type": "text",
                            "label": true
                        },
                        {
                            "externalId": "object-type-attribute/manufacturer-url",
                            "name": "Netbox URL",
                            "description": "Source URL of the manufacturer in Netbox",
                            "type": "url",
                            "label": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "mapping": {
        "objectTypeMappings": [
            {
                "objectTypeExternalId": "object-type/device",
                "objectTypeName": "Device",
                "selector": "devices",
                "description": "devices",
                "attributesMapping": [
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/device-id",
                        "attributeName": "id",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "id"
                        ],
                        "externalIdPart": false
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/device-name",
                        "attributeName": "name",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "externalIdPart": false
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/device-url",
                        "attributeName": "url",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "url"
                        ],
                        "externalIdPart": true
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/device-manufacturer",
                        "attributeName": "manufacturer",
                        "referenceObjectTypeName": "Manufacturer",
                        "referenceObjectExternalId": "object-type/manufacturer",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "device_type.manufacturer.id"
                        ],
                        "objectMappingIQL": "device_type.manufacturer.id = ${device_type.manufacturer.id}",
                        "externalIdPart": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "objectTypeExternalId": "object-type/manufacturer",
                "objectTypeName": "Manufacturer",
                "selector": "manufacturers",
                "description": "manufacturers",
                "attributesMapping": [
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/manufacturer-id",
                        "attributeName": "id",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "id"
                        ],
                        "externalIdPart": false
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/manufacturer-name",
                        "attributeName": "name",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "externalIdPart": false
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeExternalId": "object-type-attribute/manufacturer-url",
                        "attributeName": "url",
                        "attributeLocators": [
                            "url"
                        ],
                        "externalIdPart": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**device data**

```
"devices": [
        {
            "id": 88,
            "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices/88/",
            "display": "PP:B117",
            "name": "PP:B117",
            "device_type": {
                "id": 11,
                "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-types/11/",
                "display": "48-Pair Fiber Panel",
                "manufacturer": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/manufacturers/13/",
                    "display": "Generic",
                    "name": "Generic",
                    "slug": "generic"
                },
                "model": "48-Pair Fiber Panel",
                "slug": "48-pair-fiber-panel"
            },
            "role": {
                "id": 6,
                "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-roles/6/",
                "display": "Patch Panel",
                "name": "Patch Panel",
                "slug": "patch-panel"
            },
            "device_role": {
                "id": 6,
                "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-roles/6/",
                "display": "Patch Panel",
                "name": "Patch Panel",
                "slug": "patch-panel"
            },
            "tenant": {
                "id": 13,
                "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/tenancy/tenants/13/",
                "display": "NC State University",
                "name": "NC State University",
                "slug": "nc-state"
            },
            "platform": null,
            "serial": "",
            "asset_tag": null,
            "site": {
                "id": 21,
                "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/sites/21/",
                "display": "MDF",
                "name": "MDF",
                "slug": "ncsu-065"
            },
            "location": null,
            "rack": {
                "id": 41,
                "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/racks/41/",
                "display": "Plant 1",
                "name": "Plant 1"
            },
            "position": 37.0,
            "face": {
                "value": "front",
                "label": "Front"
            },
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "parent_device": null,
            "status": {
                "value": "active",
                "label": "Active"
            },
            "airflow": null,
            "primary_ip": null,
            "primary_ip4": null,
            "primary_ip6": null,
            "oob_ip": null,
            "cluster": null,
            "virtual_chassis": null,
            "vc_position": null,
            "vc_priority": null,
            "description": "",
            "comments": "",
            "config_template": null,
            "config_context": {},
            "local_context_data": null,
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": {},
            "created": "2021-04-02T00:00:00Z",
            "last_updated": "2021-04-02T17:17:28.425000Z",
            "console_port_count": 0,
            "console_server_port_count": 0,
            "power_port_count": 0,
            "power_outlet_count": 0,
            "interface_count": 0,
            "front_port_count": 48,
            "rear_port_count": 1,
            "device_bay_count": 0,
            "module_bay_count": 0,
            "inventory_item_count": 1
        },
...
```

**manufacturer data**

```
"manufacturers": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/manufacturers/11/",
            "display": "APC",
            "name": "APC",
            "slug": "apc",
            "description": "",
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": {},
            "created": "2020-12-22T00:00:00Z",
            "last_updated": "2020-12-22T02:25:37.151000Z",
            "devicetype_count": 1,
            "inventoryitem_count": 0,
            "platform_count": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": "https://demo.netbox.dev/api/dcim/manufacturers/1/",
            "display": "Arista",
            "name": "Arista",
            "slug": "arista",
            "description": "",
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": {},
            "created": "2020-12-18T00:00:00Z",
            "last_updated": "2020-12-18T03:17:05.204000Z",
            "devicetype_count": 0,
            "inventoryitem_count": 0,
            "platform_count": 0
        },
...
```